# How can I make a default value so I won't get an NaN

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am coding a task tracker when you can add and remove tasks.
Each task have id value and when you add a new task the id will be the last one + 1.
If I remove the whole tasks and then adding one the id will be NaN I would like to get some help :)

tasks -

```js
const App = () => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      text: 'Taking react course',
      day: 'Aug 29th at 9:00am ',
      reminder: true,
    },

    {
      id: 2,
      text: 'Exersice at the gym',
      day: 'Aug 29th at 1:00pm',
      reminder: true,
    },
  ]);
};
```

when Adding task -

```js
const onAdd = (task) => {
  const id = tasks[tasks.length - 1]?.id + 1; // Without this line I am getting undefined id error so thats why I putted that question mark over there.
  const newTask = { id, ...task };
  setTasks([...tasks, newTask]);
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably this could potentially resolve to `null` here:

```
tasks[tasks.length - 1]?.id
```

But you can provide a default value of `0` when that happens:

```
tasks[tasks.length - 1]?.id ?? 0
```

So this should always at least resolve to a valid number:

```
const id = (tasks[tasks.length - 1]?.id ?? 0) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally assign a value to id as follows:

we will check if tasks array is empty or not if its empty we will set `id=1` else we will go with regular logic

```
const onAdd = (task) => {
const id = tasks.length <= 0 ? 1 : tasks[tasks.length - 1]?.id + 1; 
const newTask = { id, ...task };
setTasks([...tasks, newTask]);
```